# regex match based on preceding value

Tags: regex

Is it possible to create a regex that will only match a value if it is not preceded by another value? For example, only test true if `?` is not preceded by `.php`. Like the following:

```
/(?!\.php)\?/.test( 'mypage.php?call=here' ) == false;
/(?!\.php)\?/.test( 'otherpage.asp?call=here' ) == true;
```

I've tried using the lookaheads `?!` and `?:`, but so far haven't been able to find a combination that works.

Comment: You need not look-ahead, but look-behind, which is not supported in javascript regexes.

Comment: So you want this:

Match if there is no `?`.  If there is a `?`, each `?` cannot be preceded by `.php` ?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match strings that either do not have a `?` in them, or have a `?` that is not preceeded by `.php`:

```
^(?!.*\.php\?)
```

And here is a version that will also require a `?` to be in the string:

```
^(?!.*\.php\?).*\?
```